# i have this treeview for menu assignment. i want to know that can we find out if our rows have been updated. if yes then how?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

the coding

```
foreach (TreeNode item in this.TreeView1.CheckedNodes)
{
   if (item.Checked == true)
   {
      int strTreeValue = Convert.ToInt32(item.Value);
      SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Update Role_Menu Set Role_id=('" + roleid + "')
                             Where Menu_id=('" + strTreeValue + "')", con);
      com.ExecuteNonQuery();
      da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
      ds = new DataSet();
      da.Fill(ds);
      if (ds.Tables.Count == 0)
      {
          com = new SqlCommand("insert into Role_Menu(Role_id,Menu_id) 
                          values('" + roleid + "','" + strTreeValue + "')", con);
          com.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
 }
```

in the above `if(ds.tables.count == 0)` i am trying to find if the rows have been updated or not but it is wrong and does not work. if a row is updated then how can we come to know it is updated and which one is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code as follow

```
foreach (TreeNode item in this.TreeView1.CheckedNodes)
{
   if (item.Checked == true)
   {
      int strTreeValue = Convert.ToInt32(item.Value);
      SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Update Role_Menu Set Role_id=('" + roleid + "')
                             Where Menu_id=('" + strTreeValue + "')", con);
      int i=com.ExecuteNonQuery();

      if (i<= 0)
      {
          com = new SqlCommand("insert into Role_Menu(Role_id,Menu_id) 
                          values('" + roleid + "','" + strTreeValue + "')", con);
          com.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
 }
```

### Edit 1

You don't need to use `SqlDataAdapter` and `DataSet`
If you run the SQL from your question in a `SqlCommand` and check the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery` it should tell you how many records were affected.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx):

> **Return Value**
>   
> Type: System.Int32
>   
> The number of rows affected.